# Suddenly my App.js file and all other file formate have changed to App.js.djvut and ReactNative app just topped

Tags: android, ios, react-native

ReactNative app was running good. Then suddenly it stopped working. I am using expo.

[image]

Don't know what exactly happened.

Comment: since you're using windows, you're most likely to be infected with virus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to this article https://sensorstechforum.com/remove-djvu-files-virus/, your system is infected with ransomware virus. check the detail instructions to get rid of the problem

```
The .djvu files virus has been recently spotted in the wild by security 
researchers. It is a threat that interfere with essential systems settings 
in an attempt to encode certain types of files that store valuable data
```

Comment: thanks a lot... it would be very helpful if you can suggest any solution rather than anti-viruses ... because i have already tried some of them... they found some, but o would like to decrepit my documents, and that the antivirus  did not do....

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search of the file extension `.djvut` brings up results for a ransomware virus.

I think your computer may be infected with a virus. I would look at ways to remove the virus and if you cannot, restoring your computer from a backup.

I would look for a reputable resource like malware bytes, Symantec etc for removal instructions.